# Socket.io Error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Using Reactjs And FireBase

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, firebase, sockets, socket.io

I Am Getting The Error Called

`GET http://localhost:3001/api/room/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` 
`ChatService.js:44 AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`

ChatService.js File

```
import axios from "axios";
import auth from "../config/firebase";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const baseURL = "http://localhost:3001/api";

const getUserToken = async () =\> {
const user = auth.currentUser;
const token = user && (await user.getIdToken());
return token;
};

export const initiateSocketConnection = async () =\> {
const token = await getUserToken();

const socket = io("http://localhost:3001", {
auth: {
token,
},
});

return socket;
};

const createHeader = async () =\> {
const token = await getUserToken();

const payloadHeader = {
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
},
};
return payloadHeader;
};

export const getAllUsers = async () =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/user`, header);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};

export const getUser = async (userId) =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/user/${userId}`, header);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};

export const getUsers = async (users) =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/user/users`, users, header);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};

export const getChatRooms = async (userId) =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/room/${userId}`, header);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};

export const getChatRoomOfUsers = async (firstUserId, secondUserId) =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.get(
`${baseURL}/room/${firstUserId}/${secondUserId}`,
header
);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};

export const createChatRoom = async (members) =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.post(`${baseURL}/room`, members, header);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};

export const getMessagesOfChatRoom = async (chatRoomId) =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/message/${chatRoomId}`, header);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};

export const sendMessage = async (messageBody) =\> {
const header = await createHeader();

try {
const res = await axios.post(`${baseURL}/message`, messageBody, header);
return res.data;
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
};
```

ChatRoom.js File Is

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import { getMessagesOfChatRoom, sendMessage } from "../../services/ChatService";

import Message from "./Message";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import ChatForm from "./ChatForm";

export default function ChatRoom({ currentChat, currentUser, socket }) {
const \[messages, setMessages\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[incomingMessage, setIncomingMessage\] = useState(null);

const scrollRef = useRef();

useEffect(() =\> {
const fetchData = async () =\> {
const res = await getMessagesOfChatRoom(currentChat.\_id);
setMessages(res);
};

    fetchData();

}, \[currentChat.\_id\]);

useEffect(() =\> {
scrollRef.current?.scrollIntoView({
behavior: "smooth",
});
}, \[messages\]);

useEffect(() =\> {
socket.current?.on("getMessage", (data) =\> {
setIncomingMessage({
senderId: data.senderId,
message: data.message,
});
});
}, \[socket\]);

useEffect(() =\> {
incomingMessage && setMessages((prev) =\> \[...prev, incomingMessage\]);
}, \[incomingMessage\]);

const handleFormSubmit = async (message) =\> {
const receiverId = currentChat.members.find(
(member) =\> member !== currentUser.uid
);

    socket.current.emit("sendMessage", {
      senderId: currentUser.uid,
      receiverId: receiverId,
      message: message,
    });
    
    const messageBody = {
      chatRoomId: currentChat._id,
      sender: currentUser.uid,
      message: message,
    };
    const res = await sendMessage(messageBody);
    setMessages([...messages, res]);

};

return (
\<div className="lg:col-span-2 lg:block"\>
\<div className="w-full"\>
\<div className="p-3 bg-white border-b border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700"\>
\<Contact chatRoom={currentChat} currentUser={currentUser} /\>
\</div\>

        <div className="relative w-full p-6 overflow-y-auto h-[30rem] bg-white border-b border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
          <ul className="space-y-2">
            {messages.map((message, index) => (
              <div key={index} ref={scrollRef}>
                <Message message={message} self={currentUser.uid} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
    
        <ChatForm handleFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit} />
      </div>
    </div>

);
}
```

I Am Trying To Create A Chat I Am Getting A Error Of Socket which is Socket.io Error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Using Reactjs And FireBase I am expecting someone please help me to solve this
Please Solve This Issue I Am Using MongoDB For Database And For Server Firebase Please Help ME Solve This Issue